# $\frac{d}{dx }{e(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to differentiate
$$\frac{d}{dx} e(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}$$
and I'm using the rule $\frac{d}{dx} x^n=nx^{n-1}$ to get
$$e(\ln(x-1)-2)(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-3}$$ but the result I find when using calculators is
$$e(2\ln(x-1)-2)(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-3}$$
I'm not sure where the $2\ln(x-1)$ comes from, could someone help ? Also I've seen methods using the exponent rule $$a^b=e^{b\ln(a)}$$could it be possible to explain differently than this one? Thanks

Comment: The power rule **only** works when the base is the variable and the exponent is a constant, which is not the case here.

Comment: What's the point of writing "e^1" in the title? That's just "e".

Comment: Yes, you have to use this rule, converting $(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}$ into $e^{\ln(x-1)(\ln(x-1)-2)}$ and I don't see any shorter rule...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the rule $\frac d{dx} x^n=nx^{n-1}$ only works when $n$ is a constant, which is not the case here. Here, we have something like $f(x)^{g(x)}$, which we don't have a standard derivative rule for, so we need to manipulate our function to get it into a form for which we know a rule for.

We will use the fact that $f(x)=e^{\ln(f(x))}$; that is, the exponential base $e$ and $\ln$ functions are inverses of each other. Moreover, I will ignore the $e$ at the front of the function for the moment, since it's just a constant. We have

\begin{align*}
(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}&=e^{\ln\left((x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}\right)}\\
&=e^{(\ln(x-1)-2)\ln(x-1)}&\text{by }\ln(A^B)=B\ln(A)\\
\end{align*}

Now this is something we can take the derivative of using the exponential derivative rule, chain rule, and product rule:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}e^{(\ln(x-1)-2)\ln(x-1)}&=e^{(\ln(x-1)-2)\ln(x-1)}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\cdot\ln(x-1)+(\ln(x-1)-2)\cdot\frac{1}{x-1}\right)\\
&=e^{(\ln(x-1)-2)\ln(x-1)}\left(\frac{2\ln(x-1)-2}{x-1}\right)\\
&=(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}\left(\frac{2\ln(x-1)-2}{x-1}\right)&(*)\\
&=(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-3}(2\ln(x-1)-2)\\
&=2(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-3}(\ln(x-1)-1)\\
\end{align*}

Therefore,

$$\frac{d}{dx}e(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}=2e(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-3}(\ln(x-1)-1)$$

Note: The $(*)$ step comes from the fact that $(x-1)^{\ln(x-1)-2}=e^{(\ln(x-1)-2)\ln(x-1)}$, as we found at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Let $\,\,\,\mathtt{y=e{\left(x-1\right)}^{\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}}$

$\implies\mathtt{\ln(y)=\ln\left\{e{\left(x-1\right)}^{\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}\right\}}$

$\implies\mathtt{\ln(y)=\ln(e)+\ln\left\{{\left(x-1\right)}^{\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}\right\}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,[\because\,\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)]$

$\implies\mathtt{\ln(y)=1+\left[\ln\left(x-1\right)-2\right]\cdot\ln\left(x-1\right)}$

$\implies\mathtt{\ln(y)=1+\ln\left(x-1\right)\cdot\ln\left(x-1\right)-2\cdot\ln\left(x-1\right)}$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t. x,

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{1}{y}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=0+\dfrac{d}{dx}\big[\ln\left(x-1\right)\cdot\ln\left(x-1\right)\big]-2\dfrac{d}{dx}\big[\ln\left(x-1\right)\big]}$

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{1}{y}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\ln\left(x-1\right)\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\big[\ln\left(x-1\right)\big]+\ln\left(x-1\right)\cdot\dfrac{d}{dx}\big[\ln\left(x-1\right)\big]-2\dfrac{d}{dx}\big[\ln\left(x-1\right)\big]}$

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{1}{y}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\ln\left(x-1\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{x-1}+\ln\left(x-1\right)\cdot\dfrac{1}{x-1}-2\cdot\dfrac{1}{x-1}}$

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{1}{y}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{\ln\left(x-1\right)}{x-1}+\dfrac{\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}{x-1}}$

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y\left\{\dfrac{\ln\left(x-1\right)}{x-1}+\dfrac{\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}{x-1}\right\}}$

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{dy}{dx}=e{\left(x-1\right)}^{\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}\cdot\left\{\dfrac{2\ln\left(x-1\right)-2}{x-1}\right\}}$

$\implies\mathtt{\dfrac{dy}{dx}=2e{\left(x-1\right)}^{\ln\left(x-1\right)-3}\cdot\left\{\ln\left(x-1\right)-1\right\}}$